# Why is this example of precompilation not working in Julia

Tags: julia

I am currently trying to use precompilation for a custom package in Julia. The main goal is to precompile functions which utilise StaticVectors. In general, I want to use the abstract Real type for parameters and then precompile for 2D and 3D vectors. However precompilation fails for abstract types such as Real and AbstractFloat and not the specialised Float64 and its hard for me to understand why.

Here a minimal working example to better show the problem and what I have tried:

```
module MWE
using StaticArrays: SVector

function f(v::SVector{D, Real}, s::Real)::SVector{D, Real} where {D}
    s*v
end

println(
    "precomp for (SVector{3, Real}, Real   ,) ", precompile(f, (SVector{3, Real}, Real,))    ? " succeeded" : " failed", "\n",
    "precomp for (SVector{3, Real}, Float64,) ", precompile(f, (SVector{3, Real}, Float64,)) ? " succeeded" : " failed", "\n"
    )
end

#= REPL output after generating the package and adding StaticVectors to deps:

julia> using MWE
[ Info: Precompiling MWE [4a20f9fe-1107-468f-ad25-8011b995da74]
precomp for (SVector{3, Real}, Real   ,)  failed
precomp for (SVector{3, Real}, Float64,)  succeeded
=#
```

My guess was that the precompilation will not work for abstract types, however it seems to work just fine when using Real as a parameter for the StaticVector. Again, the goal initially was calling precompile the function for *SVector{2, Real}, Real,* and *SVector{3, Real}, Real,* to skip some JIT compilation when using the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with this:

```
julia> isconcretetype(Real)
false

julia> isconcretetype(Vector{Real})
true
```

While the elements are not concrete, the container itself is. If you know C, internally `Vector{Real}` is implemented as a list of `void*` pointers, which is a perfectly concrete type of container.